# Python remove duplicate cases that are in inverted matrix

Tags: python, deduplication

I have a list that looks like this:

```
relationShipArray = []

relationShipArray.append([340859419124453377, 340853571828469762])
relationShipArray.append([340859419124453377, 340854579195432961])
relationShipArray.append([340770796777660416, 340824159120654336])
relationShipArray.append([340509588065513473, 340764841658703872])
relationShipArray.append([340478540048916480, 340671891540934656])
relationShipArray.append([340853571828469762, 340854579195432961])
relationShipArray.append([340842710057492480, 340825411573399553])
relationShipArray.append([340825411573399553, 340770796777660416])
relationShipArray.append([340825411573399553, 340824159120654336])
relationShipArray.append([340824159120654336, 340770796777660416])
relationShipArray.append([340804620295221249, 340825411573399553])
relationShipArray.append([340684236191313923, 340663388122279937])
relationShipArray.append([340663388122279937, 340684236191313923])
relationShipArray.append([340859507280318464, 340859419124453377])
relationShipArray.append([340859507280318464, 340853571828469762])
relationShipArray.append([340859507280318464, 340854579195432961])
relationShipArray.append([340854599697178624, 340845885439229952])
relationShipArray.append([340836561937641472, 340851694759972864])
relationShipArray.append([340854579195432961, 340853571828469762])
relationShipArray.append([340844519832580096, 340854599697178624])
relationShipArray.append([340814054610305024, 340748443670683648])
relationShipArray.append([340851694759972864, 340836561937641472])
relationShipArray.append([340748443670683648, 340814054610305024])
relationShipArray.append([340739498356912128, 340825992832638977])
```

As you can see there are cases that are duplicated.
e.g.

```
[340853571828469762, 340854579195432961]
```

is the same as (but inverted)

```
[340854579195432961, 340853571828469762]
```

What is the best way (with some efficiency but can live without it if need be) to remove the duplicates from this list? So in this case I would **keep** `[340853571828469762, 340854579195432961]`, but **remove** the `[340854579195432961, 340853571828469762]`.

Comment: Does the order matter? (i.e. does it matter which you keep, and if you switch the order of some that don't have duplicates?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an OrderedDict if you need to keep the order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

>>> L = [[1, 2], [4, 5], [1,2], [2, 1]]
>>> [[x, y] for x, y in OrderedDict.fromkeys(frozenset(x) for x in L)]
[[1, 2], [4, 5]]
```

**EDIT 1**

If the order is not important you can get away with a set:

```
>>> [[x, y] for x, y in set(frozenset(x) for x in L)]
[[1, 2], [4, 5]]
```

**EDIT 2**

A more generic solution that works for lists of varying lenght, not only with two elements:

```
[list(entry) for entry in set(frozenset(x) for x in L)]
[list(entry) for entry in OrderedDict.fromkeys(frozenset(x) for x in L)]
```

Comment: it shouldn't remove [1,2] it should remove it if there is [2,1] he wants them flipped if I understand correctly

Comment: It doesn't work in case `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]` are inverted. That's not what the OP requested.

Comment: Although... now getting ValueError: too many values to unpack. The list I have has more items on it, but one would assume that it should not matter. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `frozenset(x[:2])` if you want only the first two.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of `relationShipArray` is not important:

```
result = {tuple(sorted(item)) for item in relationShipArray}
```

Comment: What is `item = tuple(item)` supposed to do? It does not change `relationShipArray` in any way.

Comment: @MikeMüller items are `list`s and are not hashable, making `tuple`s to be able to make `set`.

Comment: I know this. But check what is in `relationShipArray` after the loop. Assigning to a loop variable does not change the list. BTW, you don't want a tuple anyway because the OP wants to treat also reversed items as duplicates.

Comment: @MikeMüller Oh thank! I was on hurry! Ok I'd edited my answer, about the reversed items, `item.sort()` is there to handle them.

Comment: OK. The sort does the trick. How about a one liner?:  `result = {tuple(sorted(item)) for item in relationShipArray}`

Comment: @MikeMüller For sure it's a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

One liner solution

```
relationShipArray = []

relationShipArray.append([340859419124453377, 340853571828469762])
relationShipArray.append([340859419124453377, 340854579195432961])
relationShipArray.append([340770796777660416, 340824159120654336])
relationShipArray.append([340509588065513473, 340764841658703872])
relationShipArray.append([340478540048916480, 340671891540934656])
relationShipArray.append([340853571828469762, 340854579195432961])
relationShipArray.append([340842710057492480, 340825411573399553])
relationShipArray.append([340825411573399553, 340770796777660416])
relationShipArray.append([340825411573399553, 340824159120654336])
relationShipArray.append([340824159120654336, 340770796777660416])
relationShipArray.append([340804620295221249, 340825411573399553])
relationShipArray.append([340684236191313923, 340663388122279937])
relationShipArray.append([340663388122279937, 340684236191313923])
relationShipArray.append([340859507280318464, 340859419124453377])
relationShipArray.append([340859507280318464, 340853571828469762])
relationShipArray.append([340859507280318464, 340854579195432961])
relationShipArray.append([340854599697178624, 340845885439229952])
relationShipArray.append([340836561937641472, 340851694759972864])
relationShipArray.append([340854579195432961, 340853571828469762])
relationShipArray.append([340844519832580096, 340854599697178624])
relationShipArray.append([340814054610305024, 340748443670683648])
relationShipArray.append([340851694759972864, 340836561937641472])
relationShipArray.append([340748443670683648, 340814054610305024])
relationShipArray.append([340739498356912128, 340825992832638977])
```

make an array with all lists in `relationShipArray` and their reversed peer. use then `np.unique`.

```
import numpy as np
Y = list(np.unique(np.array(relationShipArray + 
                       [X[::-1] for X in relationShipArray])))
```